# Why can't I round cor.test

Tags: r

I'm working on measuring the correlation between Month & Temp from the Mitchell data (comes with the alr3 package). I wanted to round the coefficient to the nearest thousandth, but when I added `round()` to the code I got this error:

```
Error in round(cor.test(Month, Temp), 3) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

However, if I swap `cor.test` with `cor` the rounding works. What about `cor.test` is causing the issue? And how can I adjust my code (below) to allow the rounding to work?

```
with(Mitchell, round(cor.test(Month, Temp), 3))
```

Comment: According to the documentation (See the "Value" section of `?cor.test`), `cor.test` returns a list of class "htest".  `cor` on the other hand returns a numeric value (that happens to coincide with the values of `cor.test()$estimate`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the help file for `cor.test`. The `cor.test` function returns a list with an `htest` class attribute rather than a numeric vector required by round.

Example from the help file:

```
x<-cor.test(~ CONT + INTG, data = USJudgeRatings)

is.numeric(x)
#> [1] FALSE
class(x)
#> [1] "htest"
```

You may just want to pretty print using a different number of digits, in which case you could look at the print function for this class.

```
getAnywhere(print.htest)
```

However, even though there is a `digits` argument, it is respected only for the p-value. So, you'll just have to do your own rounding:

```
structure(rapply(z,function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) round(x,3) else x,how="replace"),
  class="htest")
```

```
        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  CONT and INTG
t = -0.861, df = 41, p-value = 0.395
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.417  0.174
sample estimates:
   cor 
-0.133
```